# Kotlin Failure delivering result

Tags: android, kotlin, null

In a `Kotlin` app we are trying to upload a jpg file to an ImageView widget other similar posts [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25565568/failure-delivering-result-resultinfowho-null-request-2-result-0-data-null-c)

One concern we have is the image(jpg) is being added to the emulator by selecting `DCIM` in the `Device Manager File` and selecting upload upload We need to navigate to this `DCIM` location the first time the app is run the app does not know where the jpg is. We will post the Logcat Code and XML code

```
08-29 16:39:27.444 18552-18675/com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
08-29 16:39:27.445 18552-18675/com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer I/chatty: uid=10084(u0_a84) Binder:18552_3 identical 3 lines
08-29 16:39:27.445 18552-18675/com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
08-29 16:39:28.329 18552-18593/com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa51c7820: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa518b060)
08-29 16:39:28.331 18552-18685/com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
08-29 16:39:28.332 18552-18685/com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer I/chatty: uid=10084(u0_a84) hwuiTask2 identical 3 lines
08-29 16:39:28.333 18552-18685/com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
08-29 16:39:28.777 18552-18552/com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer W/View: dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
08-29 16:39:28.798 18552-18552/com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 3020 bytes, containing 1 windows, 11 views
08-29 16:39:30.252 18552-18552/com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer I/System.out: =============================== Intent { act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER (has extras) }
08-29 16:39:30.252 18552-18552/com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer D/CreateHabitActivity: Image was sent
08-29 16:39:30.755 18552-18593/com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa51c7820: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa518b060)
08-29 16:39:30.818 18552-18593/com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x8bfaf980 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x9957fbf0
08-29 16:39:45.615 18552-18559/com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=24KB, data=29KB
08-29 16:39:45.618 18552-18559/com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=24KB, data=29KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
08-29 16:39:45.622 18552-18552/com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer D/CreateHabitActivity: An Image WAS Choosen
08-29 16:39:45.623 18552-18552/com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer I/System.out: ------------------------------ 1   more -1
08-29 16:39:45.661 18552-18552/com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-29 16:39:45.703 18552-18552/com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer, PID: 18552
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:Pictures/water.jpg flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer/com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer.CreateHabitActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4324)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4367)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1649)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
        at com.androidstackoverflow.habittrainer.CreateHabitActivity.onActivityResult(CreateHabitActivity.kt:71)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4320)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4367) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1649) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

**CreateHabitActivity file**

```
class CreateHabitActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val TAG = CreateHabitActivity::class.java.simpleName

    private val CHOOSE_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1
    private var imageBitmap: Bitmap? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_habit)

    }// end onCreate

    fun onstoreHabit(view: View) {
        if(etTitle.text.toString().isBlank() && 
    etDescription.text.toString().isBlank()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "No Image")
            displayErrorMsg("You Need TITLE and DESCTIPTIOM")
            return
        }else if(imageBitmap == null){
            displayErrorMsg("Select Image")
            Log.d(TAG,"Image Missing")
            return

        }
            tvError.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }

    private fun displayErrorMsg(msg: String) {
        tvError.text = msg
        tvError.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    fun onChooseImage(view:View){
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.type = "image/*"
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

        val chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose Image for Habit")
        startActivityForResult(chooser, CHOOSE_IMAGE_REQUEST)
        System.out.println("=============================== "+chooser)
        Log .d(TAG,"Image was sent" )
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: 
    Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if(requestCode == CHOOSE_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == 
    Activity.RESULT_OK
        && data != null && data.data != null){
            Log.d(TAG,"An Image WAS Choosen")
            System.out.println("------------------------------ "+requestCode+"   
        more "+resultCode)
            // request is 1 and result is -1
            val bitmap = tryReadBitmap(data.data)

            bitmap?.let {
                this.imageBitmap = bitmap
                ivIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                // Line of code above on a null object reference
                Log.d(TAG,"We Updated and Read Bitmap")

            }
        }
    }

    private fun tryReadBitmap(data: Uri?): Bitmap?{
        return try{
            MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver,data)
        }catch (e:IOException){
            e.printStackTrace()
            null
        }
    }
}// end Class
```

**XML code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_lightGray"
    android:padding="8dp"
    tools:context=".CreateHabitActivity">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Eat an Apple" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Apple a Day No Doctor"
        android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"
        android:lines="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChooseImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onChooseImage"
        android:text="Choose Image"
        android:textColor="@color/color_Black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
        android:contentDescription="Select Image"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvError"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Error"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onstoreHabit"
        android:text="SAVE"
        android:textColor="@color/color_Black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Our QUESTION is how to FIX this on a null object reference ERROR with this line of code ivIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap)**

We have tested by adding and removing ? this with this line of code
`bitmap?.let` AND this line `data: Intent?`) AND changed this declaration 
 `private var imageBitmap: Bitmap? = null`

This

```
System.out.println("------------------------------ "+requestCode+"   more "+resultCode)
```

is returning a -1 for resultCode which we feel is not correct

Comment: @quocnguyen Thanks for the EDIT I was unsure if I should post Logcat as code or text Your Self Learning on GitHub is fascinating suggestion  try this in the MainActivity back button finishAffinity()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a
>   null object reference

Your `ivIcon` is null so it throws `NullPointerException`. Please make sure it exists.

Comment: This might be the issue. We have a single_card.xml file that displays the jpg (image) to select and the ImageView widget in the XML file associated with the CreateHabitActivity file has no id see posted code. When I add an id to the activity_create_habit the system sees this as a name conflict We will try to rename the second ImageView and test

Comment: This FIXED the issue. I am unsure why we did not name the second ImageView this is a Udemy course that lacks a link to the code. When ask what to Import the issue pops up In Java we use the same name all the time with no bad effects THX

Answer (score 1):

As @jaychang0917 said your ivIcon did not exists in the XML file because it did not have a name (id) The two ImageView's can have the same id (name) the CAUTION here as you noted is that you need to be careful what you and where you are Importing from. This new behavior in Kotlin is the trade off for not using findviewbyid

**So YES you can use the same id (name) in two separate XML files**

This answer was posted to clarify Grendel's comment NO NEED to vote it as useful 
we are here to share and learn together

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation of the naming convention We tried this and YES it works NOT sure how we missed the Import from the wrong resource Your Clarification great catch by jaychang0917